# Crron job not running properly

Tags: cron

Crontab runs my script but file that are fetched are of 0 kb
and when i am running my script scheduled by own i.e
./getMSC.sh $1 $2

its running and files are also fetched
Please suggest me why this is hapeening...

Comment: It's probably something on line 13.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when a script runs properly if run manually, but fails when run from cron by the same user, the problem is a full path not being specified in the script.  Your PATH variable for an interactive login session is MUCH bigger than the one your cron job is running under; so where, for example, `rsync $source $target` might work fine from the command line, when run from cron you should specify the full path: `/usr/bin/rsync $source $target` instead.

If this isn't helpful, please post back with more detail about what your script is actually doing, and what specific results you're getting.

Comment: Hi,m geeting wht u wnt to say but i have already specified full path in crontab: eg. /user/bin/getmsc.sh abc 10.110.29.10 .Actually in my script inside for loop for every node process of fetching data is running in Bg, but wen it running as cronjob it capturing 0 kb file but wen m running as ./getmsc.sh abs 10.110.29.11 it running fy9..m usuing /Ksh shell in script...pls help me out